# Enable GlassFish Compression

Tags: glassfish, gzip

How to enable glass fish compression? I enabled compression in http-lister properties
but no changed response

Answer (score 8):

- Login to admin console: `localhost:4848`
- Go to the `Network Config` > `Network Listener`
- Select the listener for which you want to enable gzip > HTTP Tab

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have min compression size set.  I don't remember from the top of my head if glassfish has a default min compression size.  Pretty much if the resource does not exceed this value in size, it won't be compressed.
2. Check if you have correct compressableMimeType set.  application/xml is not the same as text/xml, even if they're really both XMLs.

Answer (score 0):

Responses to HTTP requests in version 1.0 are not compressed. You must send your requests in **HTTP 1.1** to get gzipped responses from your glassfish server.

More over, you must add the header **"Accept-Encoding: gzip"** in your http requests.