# Enabling gzip compression in Glassfish via XML configuration

Tags: glassfish, compression, gzip, http-compression

There are a [variety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070924/enable-glassfish-compression) of [answers](http://www.vikasing.com/2010/01/enable-gzip-compression-on-glassfish-v3.html) to this question which tackle it via the admin console. I would like to enable this via Glassfish's XML configuration but have not found any documentation regarding this feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set it in the `domain.xml` under `network-config` --> `protocols`

Example:

```
<protocol name="http-listener-1">
  <http default-virtual-server="server" max-connections="250" 
    compressable-mime-type="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript" compression="on" compression-min-size-bytes="4096">
  <file-cache></file-cache>
  </http>
</protocol>
```