# How can get the actual file from the zipped file?

Tags: java, firefox, jersey, jax-rs, glassfish-3

I am returning a Zipped file say `My_File.txt.zip` from the My server side using **JAX-RS (Jersey).**  My server-side is Java.

So I am getting the `My_File.txt.zip` in the client side while downloading.

But I want the actual file `My_File.txt` while downloading in the browser.

Is it possible? 
I am working with `Glassfish 3.x`. So I there any configuration on Glassfish to do this?

Or can i change the configuration in `Firefox` (or other browsers) to do this?

Please suggest me the correct answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "asap" <-- SO is not a free coding service! Also, why zip a text file and sending that when you can use a compressed stream (`Accept-Encoding`)?

Comment: Actually It may be any file (.PNG, .doc, .txt, .html .. etc). Its a requirement in the server-side to zip it. So I must send the already zipped file to the client

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070924/enable-glassfish-compression) or [this](http://www.vikasing.com/2010/01/enable-gzip-compression-on-glassfish-v3.html) is what you are looking for. It will not send file with `zip` extension, but will compress send data with GZip which then is unzipped by browser. You can find more info [here](https://www.google.pl/search?q=glassfish+gzip+compression&oq=glassfish+gzi&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.10778j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).